# Can't Create an Announcement Page

Tags: google-sites

The usual procedure for creating an announcement page isn't working.  I go to create page, and get the usual page asking me to enter a name for my page and select a template.  The problem is that the drop down box to select the template for the page does not include 'announcement page'.

What's going on?  Is this a result of using a sample site template?  If it is a problem with this particular site template, is there a fix?

The option is present on my other sites.

Comment: Are you still seeing the same behavior? If so, can you provide more details?

Comment: I simply remade the page from scratch when I didn't have an answer. I'm certain it was related to the site template I grabbed from the gallery. Some how the creator had restricted what types of pages can be created, though I am still clueless as to how.